# Flutter speech_recognition swift build error

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, build-error

I'm getting a build error using the flutter speech_recognition package.  Try to build for iOS right now.  Haven't tested Android.

I followed the installation guide.  The package seem to load after modifying the .yaml file.  I'm using the Visual Studio IDE on a MacBook Pro.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            9.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET speech_recognition OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/abcdefg/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/speech_recognition-0.3.0+1/ios/Classes/SpeechRecognitionPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'speech_recognition/speech_recognition-Swift.h' file not found
    #import <speech_recognition/speech_recognition-Swift.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

From my dev directory.  I can find speech_recognition directories, but the .h file is not anywhere to be found.

```
abcdefg-MacBook-Pro:Development abcdefg$ !find
find . -name speech_recognition
./learning_fluter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/speech_recognition
./learning_fluter/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/speech_recognition
./learning_fluter/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/speech_recognition
./learning_fluter/ios/.symlinks/plugins/speech_recognition
./learning_fluter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/speech_recognition
abcdefg-MacBook-Pro:Development abcdefg$ find . -name speech_recognition-Swift.h
abcdefg-MacBook-Pro:Development abcdefg$
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the project has been created with the -i command as shown below: futter create -i swift [your_project_name].
2. after doing this verify that you are using in the properties of the runner SWIFT_VERSION = 4.2. since previous versions could cause this error.
3. And finally add below in podfile:

   target 'Runner' do

   use_frameworks!